# How to position web user control according to client screen

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, web-user-controls

I'm building an multi-column combo-box using asp and Ajax controls.
It works perfectly fine.
How can i set drop-down size and location according to the client screen and user control position on the page using javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use the `.style.left`, `style.top`, etc. properties of the element, and the `.scrollHeight` of the `document.body` element.  For size, you'll use `.style.height` and `.style.width`.

The elements must be styled with `position:absolute` in your CSS.  You can make their absolute position relative to a parent by styling the parent as `position:relative`.

Then, the Javascript may look like:

```
yourelement.style.top= document.body.scrollHeight + 100 + 'px';
```

...will put the element's top edge 100px from the scrolled height of the window.

---

Each element's absolute position and location can be controlled using:

```
yourelement.style.top = ...'px';
yourelement.style.bottom = ...'px';
yourelement.style.left = ...'px';
yourelement.style.right = ...'px';

yourelement.style.width = ...'px';
yourelement.style.height = ...'px';
```

To get various heights and widths, you can use `document.scrollHeight`, `document.documentElement.scrollHeight` or `document.body.scrollHeight` (depends on browser).  These also have `.scrollWidth` too.

Comment: Not working i were put these all in a function (in alert box) and called that function fro onfocus event of my user control and it shows noting.I need to the position of my user control on client screen.where exactly my control is located.

Comment: Set the control box's style to `position:absolute`.  Then use `.offsetHeight`, `.clientHeight`, and `.scrollHeight`, and the information in my answer, to do what you want.  There's no other way, so if it's not working, you need to slowly debug or do some research.

Comment: It's working.After warping up control in to a container.I'm able to get container width,height,top and left.

Comment: OK great - sounds like you're on the right track. Welcome to SO :)